# How do I suppress standard error output in PowerShell?

Tags: svn, powershell, io-redirection

In a PowerShell script automating some SVN tasks I have the following function:

```
function SvnUrlExists($url)
{
  svn info $url | out-null 2>&1
  return $?
}
```

Since this explicitly tests whether some SVN repository URL exists, I am not interested at all in any error output. However, despite everything I found about redirecting `stderr` in PowerShell suggesting `2>&1` to redirect it to `stdout`, ***this still outputs an error message***:

```
svn: warning: W170000: URL 'blahblah' non-existent in revision 26762
svn: E200009: Could not display info for all targets because some targets don't exist
```

Unfortunately, this severely messes up the output of my script.

What am I doing wrong, and how should I suppress this error output?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Just in case someone else googles for similar terms as I did:

After I have been banging my forehead against this for hours, of course I found the solution within minutes after posting the question here:

```
svn info $url 2>&1 | out-null
```

This works like a charm.

Comment: Also, if you have a larger command you can wrap it in `$() | out-null` to get the same effect.  For example: `$( svn info $url 2>&`) | out-null`.  I do this when the command is very long, or I need to break it over a few lines in a script.

Comment: @Nick: Ah, thanks. However, wouldn't it have to be `$( svn info $url ) 2>&1 | out-null`? (Note the placement of the `2>&1`.)

Comment: Oh wow, I completely misread your post. Yes, it should be `$(svn info $url) | out-null`. It depends on where you want the error checking to happen for the `2>&1`.  I can't say without testing it, but I don't think it should matter if it is inside the `)` or outside.  You might actually be able to just leave the `2>&1` off completely, like I said, without testing I can't be sure.

Comment: it works, but if you use it in a script, it will cause the error to stop the script. This might not be an intended side effect.

Comment: @Casey: "In a PS script [...] I have the following function".

Comment: I cam across this because I had a `git commit` that I couldn't get to stfu when being ran via PowerShell... I'm very close to having PS instead invoke 'git bash' t handle the git stuff. At least I can trust bash to silence stuff.

Answer (score 43):

If you want to suppress **only** standard error, use:

```
svn info $url 2>$null
```

Answer (score 8):

One can also do this:

```
svn info $url *> $null
```

See *[Suppress console output in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18780956/#comment27698289_18782669)*

[about_Redirection](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847746)

Comment: Or svn info $url 2> $null for stderr only.

Answer (score 5):

The voted answer generates an error for me. The solution ended up being the following:

```
cmd /c "MyProgram MyArguments 2>&1" | Out-Null
```

Comment: Redirecting stderr to stdout will still generate an error and stop script execution if you have $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'. But the error will not happen if you do not redirect stderr to stdout. Weird!

Comment: @RafałKłys: Weird, indeed; it is a _bug_: see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4002

Comment: For anybody tracking this, that was duped to https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3996 and there will be a fix in version v7.1.0 (still in preview), maybe hidden behind the flag `PSNotApplyErrorActionToStderr`

Answer (score 5):

**tl;dr**

```
function SvnUrlExists($url)
{

  # Suppress all output streams (external stdout and stderr in this case)
  # To suppress stderr output only, use 2>$null
  svn info $url *>$null 

  # For predictable results with external programs, 
  # infer success from the *process exit code*, not from the automatic $? variable.
  # See https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10512
  $LASTEXITCODE -eq 0
}
```

---

Your [own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11969703/45375) effectively addresses the **redirection issue**.

[Steven Penny's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24331889/45375) proposes `*>$null`, i.e. suppressing *all* output streams as a convenient alternative - it obviates the need for `Out-Null`, which I generally suggest replacing with `$null = ...` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55047179/45375).

However, there's **another problem** with the code in your question:

While it may work with your particular command, **`$?`, unfortunately, is *not* a robust indicator of whether an external program succeeded or not** - **use `$LASTEXITCODE -eq 0`** instead, because - due to a bug as of PowerShell Core 7.0.0-preview.3, reported on GitHub [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10512) - `$?` can end up reflecting `$false` even when `$LASTEXITCODE` is `0` (unequivocally signaling success).

- *Update*: If and when the pre-v7.2 [experimental feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Experimental_Features) named `PSNotApplyErrorActionToStderr` becomes an official feature, this problem will go away - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66726535/45375) for more information.

---

As for **what you tried** in your question:

```
svn info $url | out-null 2>&1  # WRONG
```

- Only *success* output is sent through to the pipeline (*stdout* output from external programs is sent to PowerShell's success output [stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection)).
- [Redirections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection) such as `2>&1` act on *individual* commands in a pipeline, not the pipeline *as a whole*.
- Therefore, if `svn info $url` produces *stderr* output, it prints straight to the *host* (console) - `Out-Null` never sees it.

Comment: "Redirections such as 2>&1 act on individual commands in a pipeline, not the pipeline as a whole." - This is what solved the problem I was having.

Answer (score 0):

Important to note is that some Powershell cmdlets do not behave correctly with these methods. Such an example is `Get-ADUser` which will output the error in case of failure no matter what trick you use:

```
PS C:\Temp\2022-09-05T08-28-46_oexvijzd.tfq> Get-ADUser -Identity "CN=administrator,DC=acme,DC=internal" 2>&1 | Out-Null
Get-ADUser : Directory object not found
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ADUser -Identity "CN=administrator,DC=acme,DC=internal" 2>&1 | Ou ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (CN=administrator,DC=acme,DC=internal:ADUser) [Get-ADUser], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

```
PS C:\Temp\2022-09-05T08-28-46_oexvijzd.tfq> Get-ADUser -Identity "CN=administrator,DC=acme,DC=internal" *>$null
Get-ADUser : Directory object not found
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ADUser -Identity "CN=administrator,DC=acme,DC=internal" *>$null
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (CN=administrator,DC=acme,DC=internal:ADUser) [Get-ADUser], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

```
PS C:\Temp\2022-09-05T08-28-46_oexvijzd.tfq> Get-ADUser -Identity "CN=administrator,DC=acme,DC=internal" *>$null | Out-Null *>$null
Get-ADUser : Directory object not found
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ADUser -Identity "CN=administrator,DC=acme,DC=internal" *>$null | ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (CN=administrator,DC=acme,DC=internal:ADUser) [Get-ADUser], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

In these cases, you will have to make `try`/`catch` blocks, or find other alternatives (e.g. [Checking for the existence of an AD object; how do I avoid an ugly error message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605893/checking-for-the-existence-of-an-ad-object-how-do-i-avoid-an-ugly-error-message)).

Hope this will save someone some unproductive head scratching.