# Can you redirect errors in a powershell script when $ErrorActionPreference is set to stop?

Tags: powershell

I have some powershell scripts with the following in them:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "stop"
trap { Write-Error $_.Exception; }
```

When calling the script from a powershell window using a powershell redirection operator:

```
c:\somescript.ps1 2> c:\error.txt
```

It will only print out the error to the powershell window and not redirect it to the file. If I remove $ErrorActionPreference = "stop" from the script, then the redirection works, but that isn't a viable option since we need the scripts to terminate if it runs into any error. I've tried using '*>' too, but that produces the same results.

Is there any way to redirect the errors to a file without having to change all the scripts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that **`$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"`**:

- ***instantly stops* (aborts) the entire script *and* the command that calls it**, `c:\somescript.ps1 2> c:\error.txt`,
- which means that the **redirection `2> c:\error.txt` is *not* performed**, and the error message displays in the console rather than being captured in the specified file.

The **workaround** is somewhat cumbersome:

Wrap the invocation of the other script in a [`try ... catch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) as follows:<sup>Tip of the hat to [FatalBulletHit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9248774/fatalbullethit) for his help.</sup>

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

try {

 c:\somescript.ps1

} catch {

  # Now you can write the error record to the file.
  $_ > c:\error.txt

  # == Optional additional actions.

  # If desired, you can additionally 
  # emit the error too (write it the error to the error stream).
  # !! -ErrorAction Continue is necessary in order to override
  # !! $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'.
  # !! Without it, the use of Write-Error itself would cause an - uncaught -
  # !! script-terminating (fatal) error. 
  Write-Error -ErrorRecord $_ -ErrorAction Continue

  # Exit the script with a nonzero exit code to signal failure
  # (which is useful if your script is called from *outside*
  # PowerShell).
  exit 1

}
```

The need to use `-ErrorAction Continue` (or temporarily set `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'`) before calling `Write-Error` in the `catch` block to avoid causing a script-terminating (fatal) error is surprising; it would also apply if your script / function is an [*advanced*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) one and you used `$PSCmdlet.WriteError($_)` instead.

Comment: Another workaround is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34813610/1334364

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at using `Try Catch Finally` for Error Trapping.

I have had the most success with that.

[Great TechNet Blog on this subject](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/07/05/weekend-scripter-using-try-catch-finally-blocks-for-powershell-error-handling/)

Comment: While this link _may_ answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts _here_ and provide the link only for reference / additional information. (Mostly) link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Agreed, i am sorry about that. Was going to come back through today and add some code behind it. As mklement0 has now down almost exactly what i was going to there is no need!