# PowerShell: Disposing of a call result within a function - best practice

Tags: powershell

I have a function, and within that function, I am calling a git function:

```
function Confirm-GitStatus
{
    # a bunch of stuff
    & git --git-dir $gitDir --work-tree $basePath  checkout $targetBranch 2>&1
    # more stuff
    return $true
}
```

The result of this is actually an array containing the result of the the git call and $true.  In order to get the result I wanted, I had to do this:

```
$disposableMessage = & git --git-dir $gitDir --work-tree $basePath  checkout $targetBranch 2>&1
```

This feels gross.  What is the best practice for making calls and tossing the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since **you're using a stream redirection anyway** - `2>&1` to merge the PowerShell error stream (from `git`'s stderr) to the success stream (from stdout)) - the simplest solution is to **redirect *all* streams** (`*`) to `$null` with **`*> $null`**; a simplified example:

```
# Note: This command produces both stdout and stderr output.
cmd /c "echo hi & dir \nosuch" *> $null

# PowerShell Core example with Bash:
bash -c 'echo hi; ls \nosuch'  *> $null
```

---

However, ***in general* consider `$null = ...` for discarding a command's (success) output**, because it:

- conveys the intent *up front*
- is faster than both `> $null` and especially `... | Out-Null` in most cases.<sup>[1]</sup>

Applied to the examples above:

```
$null = cmd /c "echo hi & dir \nosuch" 2>&1

$null = bash -c 'echo hi; ls \nosuch'  2>&1
```

---

<sup>[1] In PowerShell (Core) 6+, `Out-Null` has an optimization if the only preceding pipeline segment is a *side effect-free expression* rather than a method or command call; e.g., `1..1e6 | Out-Null` executes in almost no time, because the expression is seemingly not even executed. However, such a scenario is atypical, and the functionally equivalent  `Write-Output (1..1e6) | Out-Null` takes a long time to run, much longer than `$null =  Write-Output (1..1e6)`.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe your command to `Out-Null`.